# String parsing or RegEx pattern match

Tags: .net, regex, string, .net-4.5

Say I have the below fields in a database that are used to configure label contents in code where the contents of the <<[...]>> tags are lookups is it possible to parse these strings into an string array?

Using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) is not possible as there could be multiple seperators of the lookup fields. Can a RegEx support this?

**Fields**

```
Label: Code <<[RecLetCode]>>

Label: <<[RecResponseDate]>>: <<[RecResponseMemo]>>

Label: <<[ResponseDate]>><br><<[DateResponseDue]>><br><<[EstCompleteDate]>>
```

Comment: String parsing must be used for very simple parsing. For other stuff, Regex are very fast and much more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grab the content you can use:

```
<<\[(\w+)\]>>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qU3dW7/2)**

[image]

```
MATCH 1
1.  [15-25] `RecLetCode`
MATCH 2
1.  [40-55] `RecResponseDate`
MATCH 3
1.  [63-78] `RecResponseMemo`
MATCH 4
1.  [93-105]    `ResponseDate`
MATCH 5
1.  [115-130]   `DateResponseDue`
MATCH 6
1.  [140-155]   `EstCompleteDate`
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use the regex `\[[a-zA-Z]\]` and `Regex.Matches` to parse this out easily.

Comment: Thanks Vache, beat me to it!